# Error on the top of every drupal page?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6

I have created a website with drupal 6.34.

When i surfing to my drupal 6.34 site, i get the following error on the top of my page.I  have searched drupal but couldn't figure it out where is the setting for it. I'm wondering if i should change the code as it mentions in the error frame?
what is it and how can i turn it of in drupal 6.34.

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 903.
```

strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_field::query() should be compatible with views_handler::query($group_by = false) in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc on line 726.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 517.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::query() should be compatible with views_handler::query($group_by = false) in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 517.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_query::init() should be compatible with views_plugin::init(&$view, &$display) in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_query.inc on line 139.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_validate() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_validate(&$form, &$form_state) in /home/b15040be/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_row.inc on line 137.

[image]

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict warnings can be always turned of in your php.ini/.htaccess/settings.php so it is not a problem

http://drupal.org/node/465332#comment-1600034 explains some reasons why we can't fix it.

Comment: I used one of comment in the link above to solve a problem as below.
Installed "disable_messages" module. And disabled all messages related to strict .*.